# Python: Add Weeks to Date from df

Tags: python, dataframe, python-datetime

How would I add two df columns together (date + weeks):

This works for me:

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(startDate, format='%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(weeks = 3)`

But when I try to add weeks from a column, I get a type error: unsupported type for timedelta weeks component: Series

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(startDate, format='%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(weeks = df['Duration (weeks)'])`

Would appreciate any help thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could add 21 days?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm using a column, because weeks = 3 works fine. It's only when I try to replace 3 with a column from a df that I get my error.

Comment: Pandas has a `to_timedelta` function that you can use to convert the whole second column before adding it to the other column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pandas `to_timelta` function to transform the number of weeks column to a timedelta, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a DataFrame with a `date` column
df = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018'),
    columns=["date"]
)

# add a column `weeks` with a random number of weeks
df['weeks'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, df.shape[0])

# use `pd.to_timedelta` to transform the number of weeks column to a timedelta
# and add it to the `date` column 
df["new_date"] = df["date"] + pd.to_timedelta(df["weeks"], unit="W")

df.head()

    date       weeks    new_date
0   2018-01-01  5   2018-02-05
1   2018-01-02  2   2018-01-16
2   2018-01-03  2   2018-01-17
3   2018-01-04  4   2018-02-01
4   2018-01-05  3   2018-01-26
```